# QML QAbstractItemModel : How to insert at index i

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qabstractitemmodel

I use the `Qt example forQAbstractItemModel` and I try to add an `Item` to a given `index`.

I read the doc and I try to use [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows)

But it doesn't work as expected and instead of adding a `new Item`, it just **copy** a **already existing item**.

Here is an example:

**What I want**: When you click on the button, it will **insert at index 2** a **new animal** called '**Lion**'. But instead of that, it inserts an **already existing animal**. The function `test()` is aimed to do that.

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
//![0]
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);
//![0]

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
//![1]
};

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    Q_INVOKABLE void test() ;
    void setName(const QString &name);
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
//![1]
//!
//!
    void setContext(QQmlContext *ctx) {
        m_ctx = ctx;
    }

    void addAnimal(const Animal &animal);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

protected:

private:
    QList<Animal> m_animals;
    QQmlContext*  m_ctx;

signals:
    void dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight);
//![2]
};
//![2]
```

*model.h*

```
#include "model.h"
#include "qDebug"
Animal::Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Animal::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Animal::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}




AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const Animal &animal)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_animals << animal;
    endInsertRows();
}

void AnimalModel::test() {

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 2, 2);
    m_animals.append(Animal("Lion", "Large"));
    endInsertRows();

 }

int AnimalModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_animals.count();
}

QVariant AnimalModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_animals.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Animal &animal = m_animals[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return animal.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return animal.size();
    return QVariant();
}

//![0]
QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
//![0]
```

*model.cpp*

```
#include "model.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <qqmlengine.h>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

//![0]
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    AnimalModel model;
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Wolf", "Medium"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Polar bear", "Large"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Quoll", "Small"));

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);
//![0]

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:view.qml"));


    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2


//![0]
ListView {
    width: 200; height: 250

    model: myModel
    delegate: Text { text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onClicked: {

        }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width:50; height:50
        text:"click"
        onClicked: {
            myModel.test()
        }

    }

}
//![0]
```

*View.qml*

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is the line were you actually add the data to the model:

```
m_animals.append(Animal("Lion", "Large"));
```

you just append it to the `QList<Animal> m_animals;` instead of inserting it at the right index!?

```
m_animals.insert(2, Animal("Lion", "Large"));
```

so the model data is essentially corrupted and the data is not copied, but inserted at the wrong place.

Comment: Alright, I thought the data order of the model was not a problem for the view.
Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: Why is `m_animals.insert(2, Animal("Lion", "Large"));` not correct? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#insert And of course the order is important, the view just displays the `QList` model, and if you tell the view index 2 has changed it only updates that index and not the whole list, so it seems as the data is copied in the view, because the value at index 2 has not changed at all.

Comment: I edited my answer, you were all right ! :) Thanks again